# Form doesn't work, problem with formGroup

Tags: angular, forms, authentication

I'm trying to do login form, but I can't fix this error

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("<form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
"): ng:///AppModule/LoginComponent.html@0:6
```

I'm new in Angular and I totally don't understand what is wrong with my code.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <div class="form-field">
      <label>Email:
        <input name="username"
               formControlName="username"
               type="email">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
      <label>Password:
        <input name="password"
               formControlName="password"
               type="password">
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-buttons">
    <button class="button button-primary"
            (click)="onSubmit()">Login
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.sass']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;
  error = '';

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authenticationService.logout();
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  get f() {
    return this.form.controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
          () => {
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
          },
          error => {
            this.error = error;
            this.loading = false;
          });
  }
}
```

I did a few forms before them and I didn't get any bigger problems. The biggest surprise for me is fact that I can't find a solution in internet of this problem.

Comment: Try importing `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`

Comment: I forgot about ReactiveFormsModule - thanks!

Comment: I added the comment as an answer. Can you please upvote and mark it as answer so that it helps others

Comment: Hi, I m the first one who told you to import the reactiveformsmodule. And it is neither upvoted nor accepted. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just import the ReactiveFormsModule after BrowserModule

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // other imports ...
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to import `ReactiveFormsModule` in `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ...
```

Comment: I forgot about ReactiveFormsModule, thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

Import both the modules `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`